# Stacking two embedded SVGs in single div

Tags: javascript, html, css, svgpanzoom

I have pairs of complex black and white svg files that are generated programatically. FWIW they represent two revisions of a circuit board design.

Here are two examples

https://pastebin.com/uh6TtP0m

https://pastebin.com/MqareMLv

I am trying to compare them visually and, if I apply an feMatrix filter to each of these files and overlay them, I can obtain a view of how the two files differ.

[image: screenshot of filtered and superimposed example]

I have used pan-zoom-svg to zoom/pan both versions in lockstep in **separate** divs using this strategy so that both images can be zoomed into the same region of interest.

I would like to be able to pan and zoom the combined image. To try to achieve this I have tried placing both svgs with a fixed attribute in the stylesheet to keep them aligned. The enclosing div has a relative attribute. The images are in embed tags (I have also tried object tagging. Processing image tagged svgs is not supported in pan-zoom-svg).

The combined image does exactly what I want - I can pan and zoom it as required however, I cannot place it within a div on my final webpage as it overflows.

I am not clear if this is a defect in my code or a limitation of svg-pan-zoom. Using the same technique for individual rather than two copies of the svg works perfectly.

I am generating the comparison page for multiple revisions programatically.

The two filtered images are both aligned and pan and zoom correctly, however, I cannot seem to place them within a div to style them with  the rest of my webpage.

[EDIT to remove incorrect markup formatting hiding some text]

```js
window.onload = function() {
  // Expose variable to use for testing
  window.zoomBoard = svgPanZoom('#diff', {
    zoomEnabled: true,
    controlIconsEnabled: true,
  });

  // Expose variable to use for testing
  window.zoomBoard2 = svgPanZoom('#diff2', {
    zoomEnabled: true,
    controlIconsEnabled: true,
  });

  zoomBoard.setOnZoom(function(level) {
    zoomBoard2.zoom(level)
    zoomBoard2.pan(zoomBoard.getPan())
  })

  zoomBoard.setOnPan(function(point) {
    zoomBoard2.pan(point)
  })

  zoomBoard2.setOnZoom(function(level) {
    zoomBoard.zoom(level)
    zoomBoard.pan(zoomBoard2.getPan())
  })

  zoomBoard2.setOnPan(function(point) {
    zoomBoard.pan(point)
  })
};
```

```css
.responsivefull {
  padding: 5 5px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 3px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.diff1filter {
  filter: url(#f1);
}

.diff2filter {
  filter: url(#f2);
}

.lock {
  position: fixed;
  top: 1px;
  right: 3px;
  outline: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/svg-pan-zoom@3.6.0/dist/svg-pan-zoom.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="title">ThermocoupleLogger</div>
  <div class="subtitle">F_Cu</div>


  <svg width="0" height="0" viewBox="0 0 600 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
        <defs>
            <filter id="f1" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
                <feColorMatrix result="original" id="c1" type="matrix" values="1   0   0   0   0
                                                0   1   0   1   0
                                                0   0   1   1   0
                                                0   0   0   1  0 " />
            </filter>
            <filter id="f2" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
                <feColorMatrix result="original" id="c2" type="matrix" values="1   0   0   1   0
                                        0   1   0   0   0
                                        0   0   1   0   0
                                        0   0   0   0.5   0" />
            </filter>
        </defs>
    </svg>

  <div class="responsivefull">
    <embed id="diff" class="diff1filter lock" type="image/svg+xml" src="https://pastebin.com/raw/uh6TtP0m" style="position:absolute;" />
    <embed id="diff2" class="diff2filter lock" type="image/svg+xml" src="https://pastebin.com/raw/MqareMLv" style="position:absolute;" />
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can quite easily spot the differences with a mix of `filter` and `blend-mode`.

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Spot differences in SVGs</title>

  <style>
    :root {
      --zoom-factor: 300%;
      --pan: 0px;
      --tilt: 0px;
    }

    html, body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .overlapping-images-container {
      position: relative;
      padding: 1rem;
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .overlapping-images-container::before,
    .overlapping-images-container::after {
      position: absolute;
      content: '';
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;

      background-size: var(--zoom-factor);
      background-position-y: var(--tilt);
      background-position-x: var(--pan);
    }

    .overlapping-images-container::before {
      background-image: url('F_Cu_3c9fec.svg');
      filter: invert(1);
      z-index: 1;
    }
    .overlapping-images-container::after {
      background-image: url('F_Cu_340edd.svg');
      mix-blend-mode: exclusion;
      z-index: 2;
    }

  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="overlapping-images-container"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

http://erebaltor.se/rickard/stackoverflow/overlappingSVGs.html

I added CSS variables that you can manipulate, either via javascript or via console, so you can zoom, and move the images right-left or up and down.

[image: Example of how it can look like]

Comment: Although this highlights the differences, it does not show in quite the same way which features have been added and which removed in the same view. In the original filter function, additions are in blue and removes are red. However, it does offer an interesting way of enclosing the difference image within a single div. It is a good starting point for me to try some alternative strategies.

Comment: I'm sorry. I see now that wasn't reading your post fully. It was a late night post. I will leave my post as a proof of temporary stupidity. :) But I guess you can at least take with you the idea of using the pseudo-elements `::before` and `::after` to control the overflow in a better way.